# Changing div multiple appearance and content on div hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, opacity

Im been scratching my head for the last three days trying to figure out how to solve my problem.

What want to do on this page http://www.hungryhippo.se/test/contact.html
Is to when hovering over the office DIV the people at that office highlighted in the way of that the other people get a opacity of say 50%.

Second stage in this is at the same time either on a click or on the hover the map get replaced with the one that is relevant for that office. What I noticed when trying to solve this is that I cant use hide because the google maps widget that i get thru dreamweaver get errors and show grey bars instead of the map.

Then I used this script /TennG/ from jsfiddle

So one solution I been thinking of would be to use visibility and then the ones that are hidden would have hight 0px then get scaled up to 100% when it should be shown.

Even if you don't give me the complete code (understandable) pleas just push me in the right direction. Not a hotshot in HTML, jquery is new to me trying to catch up on that a bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The HTML at your page is too complicated (you seem to have a case of divitis) for a direct answer of exactly what you'd need to do with it, but in a general sense as long as you have some way of associating the "heading" office divs with the individual people divs it's fairly straightforward to add the fading effect. For example, you could give a `data-` attribute to the headings to specify a class that all associated people divs will have, something like this:

```
<div class="office" data-office="Stockholm">Stockholm Office</div>
<div class="office" data-office="Denmark">Denmark Office</div>
<div class="office" data-office="LA">Los Angeles Office</div>

<div class="person Stockholm">Stockholm<br>Amanda Atkins</div>
<div class="person Stockholm">Stockholm<br>Benjamin Bovington</div>
<div class="person Denmark">Denmark<br>Carolyn Carson</div>
<div class="person LA">Los Angeles<br>Dave Duncan</div>
<div class="person LA">Los Angeles<br>Evelyn Edwards</div>
```

Then add a hover handler to divs with class "office" that will use the `data-office` attribute to find the associated people - or in your case find the people that are not associated to reduce their opacity:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".office").hover(function() {
        $(".person").not("." + $(this).attr("data-office")).fadeTo(100, 0.5);
    }, function() {
        $(".person").not("." + $(this).attr("data-office")).fadeTo(100, 1);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EHrcb/

(The "person" divs could have used a `data-` attribute too, but it's simpler to select by class so that's what I went with.)

I imagine you could use the same concept to show the appropriate map for each office, but using `.hide()` and `.show()` or setting visibility or whatever rather than setting opacity.

Note that your existing html is invalid: you're not supposed to use the same `id` for multiple elements.

Comment: +1 I was using exact same data attribute, but was slower by a couple of minutes!

Comment: @charlietfl - Ha! Yes, just shows that `data-` plus `class` is the simplest solution to this type of problem. Two out of two respondents recommend it...

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks you for the response! Ya I got the digits syndrome. ;) Will look in to that. Probably doing it way to complicated then I need it to. Will look it over and work on simplify it. Im thingking everything as folders and layers as i do in the softwares Im more used to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for people using jQuery

You can add multiple classes to any element so for your people add a class that represents the city , along with a data attribute to use for panning the map( see notes in last edit at bottom of answer)

```
<div class="contact_office_people stockholm" data-map-coordinates="[ lat,lng]">
```

On your office locations DIV's add an html5 `data-` attribute for the office which can esily be read with jQuery `data()` method

```
<div class="contact_office_container" data-office="stockholm">
```

Now can use jQuery `hover()`

```
var $people=$('.contact_office_people');

$('.contact_office_container').hover(function(){
     /* this part of hover covers mouseenter event*/
     /* "this" is the current element behing hovered*/
      var peopleClassSelectorString = '.' + $(this).data('office') ; 
      $people.not( peopleClassSelectorString).css({opacity: .5});        


},function(){
    /* this part of hover covers mouseleave event*/
    $people.css({opacity: 1});
})
```

**EDIT** : As far as the google map goes, you can bind data to a map marker object that can be retrieved using marker mouseenter/mouseleave events. Once you digest the format for the classes of people and offices, you might want to create a separate question tagged with google maps to learn how to add data to a marker and retrieve it with events.

**Second Edit**: Actually the map is not difficult, you can use google maps `panTo( coordinates)` method. I added extra `data-` attribute for those.

See [google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Comment: +1 for caching the `$people`, which I couldn't be bothered to do in my answer (though ironically I've now used more keystrokes praising you for it than I would've needed to include it myself).

Comment: @nnnnnn  I think my answer took longer due to poking through what you aptly describe as `divitis`!

Comment: @charlietfl thank you

I will go in and implement this to the site and try and trim down the divs. Thank you both a bunch!

Comment: @charlietfl I have now rewritten allot of my Div mania based on "nnnnnn" setup. I got his to work but not yours. I reuploaded a cleaner HTML code to:http://www.hungryhippo.se/test/test14.html
If you please could help me also get yours going I would be really grateful. would like to test both of your code out. Thanks

Comment: the difference is I matched my class selectors to the wrappers you have on the live page, but those classes don't exist in your demo page. WHere you currently have `office` and `person` classes in the outer element for each one, the other page has the classes I used as the outer

Comment: @charlietfl I rewrote it as I understand what you suggested http://www.hungryhippo.se/test/contact2.html Sorry If I seam stupid. have not cached up on the jquery yet. So your patience is appreciated.